# How to import a local module in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook

I made a file named `bts_dataloader.ipynb` and I want to use it as a local module. I used the code in the image following some online tutorials but it gives a `ModuleNotFoundError` error. How can I import this notebook as a module?

Code:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('bts_dataloader'))
import bts_dataloader
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bts_dataloader'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first convert the `.ipynb` file to a `.py` file and then import the newly created `.py` file. At your command line:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to python bts_dataloader.ipynb
```

That will create a `bts_dataloader.py` file which could then be imported. [This](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html) appears to be another way to do it but a tad more complicated.